# How can I rearrange the voltage divider formula for R2?

Tags: voltage-divider

Can I please have a step by step explanation as to how I can rearrange the voltage divider formula to find R2. I dont understand how I end up with R2 = R1 x Vout/Vin - Vout.

Answer (score 16):

It's just manipulation of algebra. Make R2 the subject of the equation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx17vh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{out}  = V_{in}*\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$

\$(R_1+R_2)*V_{out} = V_{in}*R_2\$

\$V_{out}*R_1+V_{out}*R_2 = V_{in}*R_2\$

\$V_{out}*R_1 = V_{in}*R_2 - V_{out}*R_2\$

\$V_{out}*R_1 = (V_{in} - V_{out})*R_2 \$

\$R_2 = \frac{V_{out}*R_1}{V_{in} - V_{out}}\$