# Setting the minimum value of a potentiometer using a resistor

Tags: voltage-divider

I'm currently studying for the amateur radio exam and I've come across a question which, in theory, should be simple but it entirely eludes me.

In short:

If the potentiometer is 10KOhm what value should R3 be for Vout to be 1% of Vin at the POTs minimum setting.

*(R1 and R2 are supplementing a POT to help me think it through)*

[image: 10k pot and third mystery resistor]

I understand the potential divider [equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150771/how-can-i-rearrange-the-voltage-divider-formula-for-r2?newreg=df940fe4987d4df0a9c4f66a32ef411d), but it's the ratio that confuses me. Or more precisely how to apply that ratio to let R3 be of a sufficient value to make sure "minimum".

So my thinking started as follows:

According to my [reading](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers) if R2 is an order of magnitude higher than R1, Vin = Vout. OK great, adding to R3 shouldn't make a difference.

Conversely if R2 is smaller, the voltage will be smaller - Great

At minimum, the POT is effectively 10K. which means Vout = VIn. I presumed R1 would be 10K, whilst R2 would be 10K - I'm guessing this is wrong.

I tried flipping it over, but the same problem.

What's my glaring mistake - is there somewhere that'll teach me to fish as it were

[edit] Big thanks to everyone. I'll leave this question intact as the answers are correct. However, *my* question is in the comments (oops)

Comment: I don't see any POT in the schematic. why do you think it is 10K at it's minimum? I would say it is maximum..

Comment: "if R2 is an order of magnitude higher than R1, Vin = Vout" - err, no. Go back to the equations and use R2 = 10 * R1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pot is at its minimum setting then R2 will effectively be 0 and R1 will be 10kohm. This means:

\$ {R_3 \over (10k\Omega+R_3)} = 0.01 \$

Solving for R3 we get 100ohm (normalized for E24).

Comment: That's really odd, precisely what I thought it was. But according to the answer sheet it's 1.1kohm for R3

Comment: That would result in a minimum of 10%.

Comment: Hmm, so either I'm looking at the wrong answers (the most likely, err, answer) or the answer book is wrong.

Comment: Or you are misunderstanding the question. Why not to post the original without your interpretation?

Comment: @milesb you buried the lead. That should be in the question.

Comment: @MilesB ... Did the original question by any chance specify a load on Vout?

Comment: No load on Vout. I rewrote the question so I don't fall fowl of the copyright people. There's no mention of vin/vout voltages, just simply the minimum setting on the POT should be 1% of Vin (and that the pot is 10k)

Comment: There is no copyright issue here. academic fair use and not being able to copyright a fact. Either you stop handicapping us or you don't get a proper answer

Comment: Righteo, if I end up in Guantanamo I'm blaming you. "It is decided to limit the lowest setting of a volume control to 1% of the maximum power. The control itself is a 10k Ohm potentiometer. To achieve this a resistor is inserted between the lower connection of the potentiometer and the 0V line as shown in the diagram (the one I transposed). The value of the resistor (r3) should be... "

Comment: Ah! Tha explains everything! They asked about *POWER*, not voltage.

Comment: Yep. The relation between power and voltage is quadratic, which means that it should be 10% voltage.

Comment: Well first up _crap_, for entirely overlooking that. That said, without a known Vin, how does that help us? Would I not need to know resistance ahead of time?

Comment: The relation is quadratic *regardless of the resistance*.

Comment: Do you guys recommend any links I can look at? Still not entirely sure I understand. Without substituting volts, or resistance I'm a bit lost.

Comment: \$ P = {V^2 \over R} \Rightarrow P \propto V^2 \$

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - trying to understand. 

Experimented with rearranging the formulae without much success. Without supplementing a voltage, I'm a bit lost. 

You mention the resistance is irrelevant. And the relation is quadratic. Is there any other hints you can suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45019/discussion-between-milesb-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so R1+R2 = 10K since it's a 10K pot.

you want \$\frac{R3}{R1+R2+R3} = 0.01\$

Solve for R3, but for all practical purposes it is 100 ohms.

In other words we know R3 << R1+R2 so

\$\frac{R3}{R1+R2+R3} \approx \frac{R3}{R1+R2}\$.

Pots generally have a really **crummy tolerance** on the element resistance (+/-20% is common) so the 100 ohms isn't going to make much difference.

The (uselessly) precise solution is a bit (1%) higher (about 101 ohms- for a 2nd order approximation) or (even more uselessly) 101.0101010101010101010101010101... to be exact.

Answer (score -1):

Series R changes from R1 to R1+R2 =10.1k 
If Vout is the tap and R2 is grounded, then Vout =Vin* R1/(R1+R2) for R2 =R2*{0 to 100%)

Also this works from full CCW to full CW rotation when using pins 1&2 since tap moves from pin  1 to 3 (not shown) with CW rotation. Using pins 2&3 does the reverse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk9tfT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>